# How do I make resizers update the item position in XUL?

Tags: resize, xul

I have the following code, where a button has four resizers. When I use the top left resizer for example, it button shrinks from the bottom right, as opposed to shrinking and moving so that the top left corner follows the cursor. I've looked in Mozilla's docs and on Google, and tried adding custom on mousedown event handlers to move the thing around - but to no avail. How do I make this behave correctly?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window id="main" title="My App" width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

  <script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://ades/content/main.js"/>
    <hbox>
      <stack style="padding: 0;">
        <button id="b" label="Resizable" style="margin: 0;"/>
        <resizer dir="topleft" style="background: red; -moz-appearance: none;"
                 element="b" left="0" top="0" width="5" height="5" />
        <resizer dir="topright" style="background: black; -moz-appearance: none;"
                 element="b" right="0" top="0" width="5" height="5"/>
        <resizer dir="bottomleft" style="background: black; -moz-appearance: none;"
                 element="b" left="0" bottom="0" width="5" height="5"/>
        <resizer dir="bottomright" style="background: black; -moz-appearance: none;"
                 element="b" right="0" bottom="0" width="5" height="5"/>
      </stack>
    </hbox>
</window>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible (yet - file a bug?). Resizers can move windows and panels, but they can only resize elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to achieve what you want but if you're resizing your button it will always reposition itself in the stack (which is at the beginning of the hbox), so it will always be at the beginning of the hbox. You might try with absolute positioning but I'm not sure if that'll work either.